# Can any one recommend a vector graphics engine for reporting purposes?

Tags: c#, .net, vector, reporting

Need to develop a .NET solution to graphically represent seats in sections, plotted in a stadium layout view, and output as a report... the seats would have different colours displaying sales status...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it might look scary at first sight, but [2D drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) in .NET Framework is actually easy to use.

Here is a small example that draws a couple of color filled circles with antialised margin:

```
using System.Drawing;

...

Font font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 8);
Image reportImage = new Bitmap(270, 45);
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(reportImage))
{
    graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 
        new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), reportImage.Size));

    for (int i = 0; i != 6; i++)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(20 + i * 40, 15, 25, 15);
        graphics.FillEllipse(
            i % 2 == 0 ? Brushes.DarkOrange : Brushes.DarkKhaki, r);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, r);

        r.Offset(2, 0);

        graphics.DrawString(i.ToString(), font, Brushes.Black, r);
    }
}
reportImage.Save("C:\\test.bmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

seems simple enough that regular old GDI+ might do the trick.

You would of course have to set up a GUI in which each stadiums seating plan can be 
"mapped" by point and click.

Answer (score 0):

[Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) looks like a great tool. Haven't tested it myself...yet. But it seems very competent and supports a bunch of output *formats*